# Why won't my custom IntelliJ plugin showing up in Android Studio nor PyCharm?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, android-studio-plugin

I created an IntelliJ plugin and it shows up fine in IDEA, RubyMine, Rider, etc. But not Android studio nor in Pycharm. I have no idea why.

In Android Studio, when I search for the plugin by full plugin name, or plugin developer name the plugin simply does not come up.

However, in https://plugins.jetbrains.com/ it shows that it is indeed compatible with Android Studio.

Here is my plugin.xml file

```
<idea-plugin>
    <id>...</id>
    <name>...</name>
    <version>...</version>
    <vendor email="..." url="...">...</vendor>

    <description>...</description>

    <!-- please see http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/plugin_compatibility.html
         on how to target different products -->
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.all</depends>
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.platform</depends>
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>
    <depends>org.jetbrains.plugins.github</depends>

    <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
        <toolWindow id="Gists" anchor="right" factoryClass="..." conditionClass="..."/>
    </extensions>

    <actions>
        <action id=...>
            <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="control shift J" keymap="$default"/>

            <add-to-group group-id="EditorPopupMenu" anchor="last"/>
            <add-to-group group-id="ProjectViewPopupMenu" anchor="last"/>
        </action>
    </actions>
</idea-plugin>
```

I thought that it would be enough to simply provide the right options in the `depends` properties, which I think i am doing correctly. Unless I'm missing something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can check list of unsupported products with reasons why product is unsupported on update page (click on version in Versions tab). Module `com.intellij.modules.all` is supported only in following IDEs:

- Android Studio
- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate
- IntelliJ IDEA Community
- IntelliJ IDEA Educational
- MPS

You can check which IDEs support which modules on this page https://plugins.jetbrains.com/admin/manage-dependencies.

As for Android Studio - please check that it's build number corresponds to your plugin's `since`-`until`: for example, Android Studio 4.0 Canary 7 has build number `193.5233.102.40.6085562` - you can check in `About` menu.